# add escape character to json object flutter

Tags: json, flutter

How to convert json object like this

```
{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe"}
```

to this

```
"{\"firstname\": \"John\", \"lastname\": \"Doe\"}"
```

thank you.

Comment: you can try using jsonEncode(<yourfirstobject>).toString();

Answer (score 0):

Let's try

```
void main() {
  var data = {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe"};
  Map<String, dynamic> newMap = {};
  data.keys.toList().forEach((key) {
    newMap.addAll({"\\${key}\\": "\\${data[key]}\\"});
  });
  print(newMap);//{\firstname\: \John\, \lastname\: \Doe\}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```dart
final data = {"name": "John"};
print(jsonEncode(data).replaceAll('"', '\\"'));
```