# How to change json values to custom string format with slashes the right way in flutter, dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to transform this json format.

```
{

    "order": {

        "user_id": 69,

        "user_address_id": 0,

        "price_total": 10,

        "discounted_price": 20,

        "delivery_fee": 20,

        "total": 222,

        "menu_id": [1]

    },

    "order_items": [

        {

            "variation_id": 1,

            "menu_id": 1

        }

    ]

}
```

to this format below.

```
{

    "order": "{\"user_id\":1,\"user_address_id\":1,\"external_user_id\":\"1\",\"status\":\"received\",\"price_total\":50,\"discounted_price\":45,\"delivery_fee\":5,\"total\":50,\"menu_id\":[1,2,3]}",

    "order_items": "[{\"variation_id\":1,\"is_discount\":0,\"menu_id\":1},{\"variation_id\":4,\"is_discount\":0,\"menu_id\":1},{\"variation_id\":4,\"is_discount\":0,\"menu_id\":2},{\"variation_id\":4,\"is_discount\":0,\"menu_id\":4}]"

}
```

I try JsonEncode() method. but that doesn't give me the desired format with slashes.

I tried manually doing. but slashes disappear when i assigned the json values to a map. Any idea?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70060609/add-escape-character-to-json-object-flutter .. But why do you want to add escape slashes. It doesn't make sense. It'll make JSON invalid !!